# Size and MD5 hash of files on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

According to the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files), the size and MD5 hash of files is available through the API. Each resource (file) has an `md5Checksum` and a `fileSize`:

> `md5Checksum (string):` An MD5 checksum for the content of this file. This is populated only for files with content stored in Drive.
>
> `fileSize (long):` The size of the file in bytes. This is populated only for files with content stored in Drive.

How can I access them through Google's web interface? I'd like to avoid coding my own interface just for this.

Comment: Do you mean Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be no way through Google Drive's interface (yet), however for a quick *manual* way you can use [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to call the Drive APIs List Files service and get the md5Checksum. I needed this to verify that some personal large file I uploaded got there properly, hence the answer is not exactly tailored for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

## API instructions

Google Developers - OAuth 2.0 Playground:

- https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Step 1: Select & authorize APIs:

- Expand "Drive API v3".
- Enable "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly".
- Click "Authorize APIs".
- Click "Allow".

Step 2: Exchange authorization code for tokens:

- Click "Exchange authorization code for tokens".

Step 3: Configure request to API:

- Enter the "Request URI".
- Click "Send the request".

## Request URI instructions

### All files in folder

Get specific fields of files in a folder:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="folderId"+in+parents&fields=files(md5Checksum,+originalFilename,+size)
//
```

Replace "folderId" with the folder ID.

You can use `&fields=files(*)` to get all of the file's fields.

### Single file

Get specific fields of a file:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?fields=md5Checksum,+originalFilename,+size
//
```

Replace "fileId" with the file ID.

You can use `&fields=*` to get all of the file's fields.

## Parsing the JSON response

- Open a JavaScript console.
- Save the object into a variable.
- Map the object.
- Copy the result.

### Code

```
var response = {
  "files": [
    {
      "md5Checksum": "0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661", 
      "originalFilename": "a.txt"
    }, 
    {
      "md5Checksum": "92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f", 
      "originalFilename": "b.txt"
    }
  ]
};


var result = response.files.map(function (file) { return (file.md5Checksum + " *" + file.originalFilename); }).join("\r\n");

console.log(result);
copy(result);
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part where the Asker said: _"How can I access them through Google's web interface? I'd like to avoid coding my own interface just for this."_

Comment: This is a decent enough method for me since I don't have to create any files or install pip packages, but the `q` parameter was giving me a bit of trouble, probably since a novice like doesn't know how to extract the ID of a folder. However, going by [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), I replaced it with `corpora=user` to simply list all my files, and I could just search through the JSON output.

Comment: @Varad Mahashabde, The folder ID is in the address bar. Looks like this `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0123456789abcdefABCDEF012345`. The `0123456789abcdefABCDEF012345` would be the folder ID.